# Diagonal of an inverse of a sparse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Inverse of a sparse matrix could be dense, but what if I'm only interested in the main diagonal of the result? Is there a method that is more efficient than computing the full inverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in work of Jok M. Tang and Yousef Saad.  Their recent paper "[Domain-decomposition-type methods for computing the diagonal of a matrix inverse](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/PDF/umsi-2010-114.pdf)" has the following abstract:

[image]

Comment: The slides PEV linked to are by Saad, so there is some redundancy in our answers.

Comment: I was hoping for something that I could quickly implement using standard linear algebra routines, I guess it's not possible

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/PDF/Sparse_days_06_15_2010.pdf)(explanation of how to find diagonal of an inverse of a sparse matrix) should help.

Answer (score 1):

We recently implemented in our solver PARDISO such as option where you can these results.  The software is available at www.pardiso-project.org.

It is not yet documented in the manual b

Regards,
Olaf